# Notation to ask Wolfram Alpha the next number in a pattern

Tags: wolfram-alpha

If I have this pattern:

1 goes to 40

1000 goes to 1360

10000 goes to 3480

How do I ask Wolfram Alpha what 20,000,000 goes to?

This is my attempt:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%3E+40%2C+1000-%3E+1360+%2C+10000+-%3E3480%2C+20000000+-%3E+y+

Comment: Is that an arithmetic or geometric progression? Could you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I don't have know the terminology to articulate what I am trying to do. Given that pattern I have shown, what notation would I use to ask wolfram alpha what 20million goes to.

Comment: Do you know the formula used to get those results?

Comment: Nope. I was hoping I could insert the pattern and wolfram could plot the graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am pretty sure that Wolfram cant solve stuff without a formula. 
So i tried a couple things. .

First I tried to Plot it out, which got me part of the way there but did not give me the full graph. 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F40%2C+1000%2F1360%2C10000%2F3480+

So next i went to a buddy of mine who is more a nerd then i am who has a program on his computer that given a set of numbers will find a formula that can generate more in that set. The program is called **Eureqa** and the formula it generated that fit the first 3 numbers in the set was **38.574093 + 1.426013*x - 0.00010458704*x*x**

Plugging 20 000 000 into the equation got a value of -41806295701

and here is your graph of the formula via wolfram 
[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+38.574093+%2B+1.426013*x+-+0.00010458704*x*x](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%2038.574093%20%2b%201.426013%2ax%20-%200.00010458704%2ax%2ax)

Comment: Eureqa found a slightly better fitting equation. `(100546.73 + 4841.2861*x)/(2633.7004 + x)`but it yields a pretty drastically different result for 20 000 000. the problem is that with such a  small data set to work there are multiple 'solutions' that could fit.

Answer (score 4):

As Phwd pointed out, the key word in Wolfram|Alpha is "fit", so
[`fit {{1,40},{1000,1360},{10000,3480}}`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fit%20%7B%7B1,40%7D,%7B1000,1360%7D,%7B10000,3480%7D%7D)
will give you some least square fits to a linear, log and periodic (sinusoidal) functions. But none of these work very well.

However, if you want to be more specific, in this case W|A actually accepts the normal Mathematica input (this is not always the case). 
Since the data looks logarithmic + corrections, I tried
[Fit[{{1,40},{1000,1360},{10000,3480}}, {1, x, x^2, Log[x]}, x]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fit%5B%7B%7B1,40%7D,%7B1000,1360%7D,%7B10000,3480%7D%7D,%20%7B1,%20x,%20x%5E2,%20Log%5Bx%5D%7D,%20x%5D)
to find the least squares fit. The result was
`39.8988 + 0.101156 x + 8.141317224831925*^-6 x^2 + 175.282 Log[x]`

(Aside: you could also try taking the [log of the x values first, then a quadratic fit](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic%20fit%20%7B%7B0,40%7D,%7B3,1360%7D,%7B4,3480%7D%7D)).

As expected, with 4 free parameters and 3 data points, we get a very good fit!
[image]

The extrapolation up to `x=20,000,000` should not be trusted (but I find 3.25855*10^9).

Comment: That notation doesn't work for me, it gives an output of `{(Fit[data, funs, vars] | 40 Fit[data, funs, vars]
1000 Fit[data, funs, vars] | 1360 Fit[data, funs, vars]
10000 Fit[data, funs, vars] | 3480 Fit[data, funs, vars]), {1, x, x^2, log(x)}, x}`

Comment: @endolith: I'm not quite sure what you're talking about...

Comment: `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=[Fit{{1%2C40}%2C{1000%2C1360}%2C{10000%2C3480}}%2C+{1%2C+x%2C+x^2%2C+Log[x]}%2C+x]`

Comment: @endolith: Sorry about that, there was a problem with escaping the square bracket in the link text, which meant the bracket was in the was in the wrong place -- for some reason this broke W|A's natural language input processing and it returned half-baked nonsense. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for regression analysis.
So first you would need to understand according to your data what you would expect.

Is it a wave, is it exponential, quadratic? This type of information leads to better results. On first inspection, one could see a linear regression will not do.

[image: Linear fit]
<sub>[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear+fit+{1%2C+40}%2C{1000%2C+1360}%2C{10000%2C+3480}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20fit%20%7B1,%2040%7D,%7B1000,%201360%7D,%7B10000,%203480%7D)</sub>

So the next step (within Wolfram's limitation) is a quadratic, which fits but only because there are so little points.

> -0.000108587 x^2+1.43002 x+38.5701

Which agrees with what **[@Mickey](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15891/notation-to-ask-wolfram-alpha-the-next-number-in-a-pattern/16207#16207)** is saying

[image: Quadratic fit]
<sub>[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic+fit+{1%2C+40}%2C{1000%2C+1360}%2C{10000%2C+3480}](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=quadratic%20fit%20%7B1,%2040%7D,%7B1000,%201360%7D,%7B10000,%203480%7D)</sub>

The same could be achieved for cubic (i.e. no x^3),

> -0.000108587 x^2+1.43002 x+38.5701

Exponential (exponential fit) and Logarithmic (log fit) do not work well.